# Good Java graph algorithm library?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

Has anyone had good experiences with any Java libraries for Graph algorithms. I've tried [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) and found it ok, and there are a lot of different ones in google. Are there any that people are actually using successfully in production code or would recommend?

To clarify, I'm not looking for a library that produces graphs/charts, I'm looking for one that helps with Graph algorithms, eg minimum spanning tree, Kruskal's algorithm Nodes, Edges, etc. Ideally one with some good algorithms/data structures in a nice Java OO API.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If you were using JGraph, you should give a try to [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) which is designed for algorithms.  One of its features is visualization using the JGraph library. It's still developed, but pretty stable. I analyzed the complexity of JGraphT algorithms some time ago.  Some of them aren't the quickest, but if you're going to implement them on your own and need to display your graph, then it might be the best choice.  I really liked using its API, when I quickly had to write an app that was working on graph and displaying it later.

Comment: JGraph does have an analysis package now that includes a range of analysis functions, http://jgraph.github.com/mxgraph/java/docs/index.html.

Answer (score 71):

Summary:

- [JGraphT](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/) if you are more interested in data structures and algorithms.
- [JGraph](https://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) if your primary focus is visualization.
- [Jung](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com), and [BFG](http://bfo.com/products/graph/) are other things people tried using.
- [Prefuse](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse) is a no no since one has to rewrite most of it.
- [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) if you need good datastructures only.
- [Apache Commons Graph](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-graph/). Currently dormant, but provides implementations for many algorithms. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANDBOX-458 for a list of implemented algorithms, also compared with Jung, GraphT, Prefuse, [jBPT](https://github.com/jbpt/codebase)

Comment: Alot of those are extremely complicated... Using factory Methods and so forth.  I just need something simple to prep for an interview.  Any ideas?

Comment: If these are complicated than what kind of job you are looking for

Comment: Graph algorithms are explained here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-data-structure-and-algorithms/ with simple code

Answer (score 41):

Check out [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) for a very simple and powerful Java graph library that is pretty well done and, to allay any confusion, *is different than JGraph*. Some [sample code](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/HelloWorld):

```
UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> g =
        new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);

    String v1 = "v1";
    String v2 = "v2";
    String v3 = "v3";
    String v4 = "v4";

    // add the vertices
    g.addVertex(v1);
    g.addVertex(v2);
    g.addVertex(v3);
    g.addVertex(v4);

    // add edges to create a circuit
    g.addEdge(v1, v2);
    g.addEdge(v2, v3);
    g.addEdge(v3, v4);
    g.addEdge(v4, v1);
```

Comment: This is a great demo here https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/DirectedGraphDemo

Answer (score 37):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) is a good option for visualisation, and also has a fairly good set of available graph algorithms, including several different mechanisms for random graph creation, rewiring, etc. I've also found it to be generally fairly easy to extend and adapt where necessary.

Comment: Packages hep.aida.* are LGPL (http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/license.html). This is imported via colt (http://jung.sourceforge.net/download.html). This prevents JUNG from being used in projects under the umbrella of ASF and ESF.
Maybe one should use the github fork https://github.com/rortian/jung2 and remove that dependency. https://github.com/rortian/jung2/commit/f4ca0cdcd3312589cbb48de7350b84cbff6067b9 is mirroring the last CVS commit. The current commits seem to remove visualization functionality.

Comment: There is no released since 2010, I think that this project is abandoned

Answer (score 15):

Apache Commons offers [commons-graph](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-graph/). Under  http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/sandbox/graph/trunk/ one can inspect the source. Sample API usage is [in the SVN](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/sandbox/graph/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/graph/model/BaseMutableGraphTestCase.java?view=markup), too. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SANDBOX-458 for a list of implemented algorithms, also compared with Jung, GraphT, Prefuse, [jBPT](https://github.com/jbpt/codebase)

[Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained) if you need good datastructures only.

[JGraphT](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht) is a graph library with many Algorithms implemented and having  (in my oppinion) a good graph model. [Helloworld Example](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki/HelloWorld). License: LGPL+EPL.

[JUNG2](http://jung.sourceforge.net) is also a BSD-licensed library with the data structure similar to JGraphT. It offers layouting algorithms, which are currently missing in JGraphT. The most recent commit is from 2010 and packages `hep.aida.*` are LGPL (via the [colt library](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/license.html), which [is imported by JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/download.html)). This prevents JUNG from being used in projects under the umbrella of ASF and ESF. Maybe one should use the [github fork](http://github.com/rortian/jung2) and remove that dependency. [Commit f4ca0cd](https://github.com/rortian/jung2/commit/f4ca0cdcd3312589cbb48de7350b84cbff6067b9) is mirroring the last CVS commit. The current commits seem to remove visualization functionality. [Commit d0fb491c](https://github.com/rortian/jung2/commit/d0fb491c0b5d2156e12df3a344521cfe7581c3d8) adds a `.gitignore`.

[Prefuse](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse) stores the graphs using a matrix structure, which is not memory efficient for sparse graphs. License: BSD

[Eclipse Zest](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/zest/) has built in graph layout algorithms, which can be used independently of SWT. See [org.eclipse.zest.layouts.algorithms](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gef/org.eclipse.zest.git/tree/org.eclipse.zest.layouts/src/org/eclipse/zest/layouts/algorithms). The graph structure used is the one of [Eclipse Draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/), where [Nodes are explicit objects](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/draw2d/graph/DirectedGraph.html) and not injected via Generics (as it happens in Apache Commons Graph, JGraphT, and JUNG2).

Answer (score 12):

http://neo4j.org/ is a graph database that contains many of graph algorithms and scales better than most in-memory libraries.

Comment: is there any Neo4J client (java client) where you can visualize it?

Answer (score 11):

In a university project I toyed around with yFiles by [yWorks](http://www.yworks.com) and found it had pretty good API.

Comment: I've used yFiles for visualisation of interdependencies between data items (as part of a commercial software platform). I didn't really use any graph analysis algorithms, but check if the y.algo package has what you need:
http://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles/doc/api/

Comment: yFiles is not opensource, but offers commercial licenses

Answer (score 9):

check out [Blueprints](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki):

Blueprints is a collection of interfaces, implementations, ouplementations, and test suites for the property graph data model. Blueprints is analogous to the JDBC, but for graph databases.  Within the TinkerPop open source software stack, Blueprints serves as the foundational technology for:

[Pipes](http://pipes.tinkerpop.com/): A lazy, data flow framework

[Gremlin](http://gremlin.tinkerpop.com/): A graph traversal language

[Frames](http://frames.tinkerpop.com/): An object-to-graph mapper

[Furnace](http://furnace.tinkerpop.com/): A graph algorithms package

[Rexster](http://rexster.tinkerpop.com/): A graph server

Answer (score 7):

JDSL (Data Structures Library in Java) should be good enough if you're into graph algorithms - http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd never come across it. Are you using it?

Comment: Yes, I am using it. I started using it maybe 4 years ago. So far so good, I just wish there was a port of that for .NET, too.

Comment: Sadly, the jdsl.org page seems to be a spam page now.

Comment: I have updated the link in the original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

http://incubator.apache.org/hama/ is a distributed scientific package on Hadoop for massive matrix and graph data.

Answer (score 5):

For visualization our group had some success with [prefuse](http://prefuse.org/).  We extended it to handle architectural floorplates and bubble diagraming, and it didn't complain too much.  They have a new Flex toolkit out too called Flare that uses a very similar API.

UPDATE:
I'd have to agree with the comment, we ended up writing a lot of custom functionality/working around prefuse limitations.  I  can't say that starting from scratch would have been better though as we were able to demonstrate progress from day 1 by using prefuse.  On the other hand if we were doing a second implementation of the same stuff, I might skip prefuse since we'd understand the requirements a lot better.

Comment: What were your personal thoughts with prefuse? At my last job, a project started to use it, but ended up with a 90%+ rewritten (and optimized, with additions of new features) version of prefuse.

Answer (score 5):

Try Annas its an open source graph package which is easy to get to grips with

http://annas.googlecode.com

Answer (score 5):

It's also good to be convinced that a Graph can be represented as simply as :

```
class Node {
   int value;
   List<Node> adj;
}
```

and implement most the algorithms you find interesting by yourself. If you fall on this question in the middle of some practice/learning session on graphs, that's the best lib to consider. ;)

You can also prefer adjacency matrix for most common algorithms :

```
class SparseGraph {
  int[] nodeValues;
  List<Integer>[] edges;     
}
```

or a matrix for some operations :

```
class DenseGraph {
  int[] nodeValues;
  int[][] edges;     
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I'd call it production-ready, but there's [jGABL](http://jgabl.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

If you need performance, you might take a look at Grph. The library is developed in the French University and CNRS/Inria.

http://www.i3s.unice.fr/~hogie/grph/

The project is active and reactive support is provided!

Answer (score 3):

Instructional graph algorithm implementations in java could be found here (by prof. Sedgewick et al.):
http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/code/

I was introduced to them while attending these exceptional algorithm courses on coursera (also taught by prof. Sedgewick):

https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI

https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partII

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually looking for Charting libraries and not for Node/Edge Graph libraries I would suggest splurging on Big Faceless Graph library ([BFG](http://big.faceless.org/products/graph/)).  It's way easier to use than JFreeChart, looks nicer, runs faster, has more output options, really no comparison.

Comment: You misunderstood the question: it is about the kind of graphs that have nodes and edges, not the kind that has pies and bars.

Answer (score 0):

JGraph from http://mmengineer.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-graph-floyd-class.html

Provides a powerfull software to work with graphs (direct or undirect). Also generates Graphivz code, you can see graphics representations. You can put your own code algorithms into pakage, for example: backtracking code. The package provide some algorithms: Dijkstra, backtracking minimun path cost, ect..