# Java - Which is the best implementation structure for Graph?

Tags: java, graph

The graph is very large but undirected. Edges are unweighted.

In my implementation, I have to find the vertex with max degree and do deletion on both vertexes and edges.

Linked list? ArrayList? Map?

Which one is better for my implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My suggestion would be to store the vertexes in a priority queue. That way you can have very fast access to the vertex with the highest degree. As for how to implement the vertexes, I would store each neighboring vertex in some kind of set data-structure such as a HashSet or a TreeSet to be able to remove stuff efficiently. I wouldn't represent the edges explicitly, it's not needed.

Code, something along the lines of:

```
class Graph {

  PriorityQueue<Vertex> vertexes;

  public Graph() {
    vertexes = new PriorityQueue<Vertex>(10,new Vertex());
  }

  public Vertex maxDegreeVertex() {
    return vertexes.peek();
  }

  ...

}

class Vertex implements Comparator<Vertex> {
  HashSet<Vertex> edges;

  public Vertex() {
    edges = new HashSet<Vertex>();
  }

  public compare(Vertex v1, Vertex v2) {
    v2.edges.size().compareTo(v1.edges.size());
  }

  ...

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the code..
I never use PriorityQueue before, is it easy to do deletion??

Comment: Yep, it's real simple. If you want to remove the element with highest priority at the same time at retrieving it, just use the poll method. Removing elements in general is done using the remove method. Just google "priority queue java" for the documentation.

Comment: Got it, thanks!
One more question, what is the purpose for putting method compare in vertex class?

Comment: Oh, it's a bit of a hack I suppose but it makes it easier to implement the compare method. I wanted to feed the priority queue my own custom made comparator. And in order to implement it I needed access to the number of neighbors of a vertex. Since I didn't want to clutter the code snippet with that kind of stuff I just put the compare method in the Vertex class. But you'd be better off implementing is somewhere else, perhaps as an anonymous class created when you create the PriorityQueue.
Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Vertex should implement Comparable instead of Comparator, to define the natural order. That way you don't have to specify the comparator.

Comment: Wouldn't this be slow, O(n), on every remove vertex? And how would one implement delete edge without messing with the priority queue constraint on fixed priorities?

Answer (score 16):

The two fundamental data structures for representing graphs are the

- `adjacency list`
- `the adjacency matrix`

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix.
The articles also discuss the pros and cons of those two structures.

Comment: My book on data structures suggests an adjacency map, which is an adjacency list with the secondary list replaced with a map. This decreases the expected running time of some of its methods. (Data Structures & Algorithms in Java by Goodrich, Tamassia and Goldwasser)

Answer (score 3):

From the above suggested the answer would be

Map with LinkedList...

Your datastructure could be like this(varies according to your requirement)...

```
Map<?, List<?>>
<Node-name, List-of-nodes-connected-to-it>
```

Basically, Graphs are best implemented with the help of HASHING and the above datastructure helps a lot in that..

Comment: This is not true, hashing isn't always best, sometimes an Adjacency Matrix is the best structure. It depends on the algorithm.

Comment: Also, not all maps use Hashing, for example TreeMap doesn't.

Comment: What do you mean by 'depends on the algorithm'? Can give any example?

Comment: Any algorithm which has a critical stage finding if two vertexes are adjacent. This is O(1) in a matrix and O(min(A,B)) in a list where A and B are the degree of the vertex

Answer (score 1):

If your algorithm requires looking up on max degree, then you want a data structure ordered by degree, something like a PriorityQueue would be good.

Then you need to store the graph itself. For deletion quickly I'd recommend something like a Sparse Array structure. If you have to use java.util data structures, then a `HashMap` from vertexes to the list of connected vertexes offers O(1) deletion.

If you could use 3rd party libraries, then there are [a list of answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library) of which JGraph and JUNG seem most popular.

Answer (score 1):

Graph implementation depends on what you going to do with it. But for most cases Adjacency list based implementation helps.

In Java you can do it using a Map<>. Here is generic Adjacency List based [Graph.Java](http://geekrai.blogspot.com/2014/08/graphjava.html) implementation on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

You could also have a look at specifically-designed libraries, like [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what other requirements you have. A naive, simple approach could be

```
class Node
{
  List<Node> edges;
  int id;
}
```

where you'd have a List of all the nodes in the graph. The problem is this can become inconsistent; e.g. node A might be in node B's edges list, but node B might not be in node A's list.  To get around this, you could model it as such:

```
class Edge
{
  Node incidentA;
  Node incidentB;
}

class Node
{
  int id;
}
```

Again, you'd have List and List of all the edges and nodes in the system. Of course analyzing this data structure would be done in a very different way than in the other approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Graph {
    private Set<Vertex>vertices;
    private Set<Edge>edges;
    private Map<Vertex,List<Edge>>adj;
    // Getter setter



    public Graph(Set<Vertex> vertices, Set<Edge> edges, Map<Vertex, List<Edge>> adj) {
        super();
        this.vertices = vertices;
        this.edges = edges;
        this.adj = adj;
    }
}

// Vertex class
public class Vertex {
    private String name;

    public Vertex(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }


}

// Edge class 

public class Edge {
    private Vertex from;
    private Vertex to;
    private int weight;

    public Edge(Vertex from, Vertex to,int weight) {
        super();
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.weight = weight;
    }


}

// Driver class 

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {
    public static void  main(String[]args) {
        Graph gr = new Graph();
        Vertex a = new Vertex("a");
        Vertex b = new Vertex("b");
        Vertex c = new Vertex("c");
        Vertex d = new Vertex("d");
        Vertex e = new Vertex("e");
        Vertex f = new Vertex("f");
        Vertex g = new Vertex("g");


        Set<Vertex>vertices = gr.getVertices();
        if(vertices == null){
            vertices  = new HashSet<>();
            vertices.add(a);
            vertices.add(b);
            vertices.add(c);
            vertices.add(d);
            vertices.add(e);
            vertices.add(f);
            vertices.add(g);
        }

        Edge ae = new Edge(a, e, 3);        
        Edge ac = new Edge(a, c, 1);
        Edge cf = new Edge(c, f, 9);
        Edge cd = new Edge(c, d, 4);
        Edge eb = new Edge(e, b, 2);
        Edge bd = new Edge(b, d, 5);
        Edge df = new Edge(d, f, 7);

    Set<Edge>edges = gr.getEdges();
    if(edges == null){
        edges = new HashSet<Edge>();
        edges.add(ae);
        edges.add(ac);
        edges.add(cf);
        edges.add(cd);
        edges.add(eb);
        edges.add(bd);
        edges.add(bd);
    }
        gr.setVertices(vertices);
        gr.setEdges(edges);

    }

}
```