# Java standard library - graph?

Tags: java, graph

Is there a representation of a graph in Java standard libraries, like there is in the boost library in C++? Is there a graph representation which is a standard in the business?

**Edit:** by graph, I mean of course the mathematical concept in computer science - [graph theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

Comment: Are you talking about the nodes-and-edges kind of graph or the visual kind of graph? (I'm guessing the former since you mentioned boost though I'm not too familiar with boost myself)

Comment: Precisely because he mentions boost, then I think it's the nodes-and-edges kind of graph.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081676/looking-for-open-source-tool-for-drawing-charts-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Java graph algorithm library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I had not looked at JUNG until now but quick glance at the API looks promising. It uses generics rather than having first-class types for Nodes and Edges. This is important when you are dealing with a moderately large volume of data. Massive volumes of data (where everything cannot/should not be maintained in RAM) would require additional limitations or abstractions at the API level.

Comment: last release: 24 January 2010

Answer (score 3):

Not in the standard libraries, but there are [lots of open source options](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-graph-network-visualization-in-java/view).  [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/) looks like it probably has what you need.

Answer (score 1):

the question is rather old, but to be complete, note there's also [gephi](http://gephi.org/) [toolkit](https://gephi.org/toolkit/). gephi is a software providing a GUI and allowing to analyze and display graphs. the classes used for representing and processing graphs are available as independent modules.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a Graph structure in stander library tho. You can build your own customized graph for your use.