# Graph recognition software

Tags: algorithm, math, graph-theory

[ISGCI](http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/classes.cgi) lists a lot of graph classes, many of which are recognizable in polynomial time. Is anyone here aware of actual implementations of these algorithms?

Comment: (Not related to the question) What's the point of identifying a graph to be ["(2P3,3K2,C4  ∪ P2,C6,K2,3,P6,X130,X132,X134,X152,X153,X154, X155,X156,X157,X158,X18,X84,X11,X127,X128,X129,X131, X133,X135,X136,X137,X138,X139,X140,X141,X142,X143,X144,X145, X146,X147,X148,X149,X150,X151,X30,X35,X46, co-XF12n+3,co-XF62n+3,co-antenna,co-eiffeltower,co-longhorn,domino,fish,odd anti-hole)-free"](http://wwwteo.informatik.uni-rostock.de/isgci/classes/AUTO_2028.html)?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library) may help you.  Every language is going to have a few basic graph theory libraries.  If you want something specific you should post specifically what you're looking for.