# Good Graph algorithm library

Tags: algorithm, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)

Does anyone know good library dealing with graph theory and algorithm ? The size of the graph I will process is huge (millions of nodes), Java based would be better, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/).

Comment: hey marcog, can this dealing with millions of nodes, does it better than JUNG ?