# Java library for graphs

Tags: java, graph, graph-theory, social-networking

what is the best Java library for manipulating graphs (specifically, for social network analysis)? I've seen Jung, but I was wondering if you knew anything better (I don't need to visualize networks, only computation).

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good Java graph algorithm library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)

Comment: I this person is looking for a graphical graph library, but is a duplicate nonetheless.

Comment: @javamonkey79: First thought so too, but to quote from the question: _I don't need to visualize networks, only computation_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found [jgrapht](http://www.jgrapht.org/) pretty useful - it has all the major algorithms (e.g. Bellman-Ford, ...)

Answer (score 2):

[neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) is the choice

And [here](http://neo4j.org/doc/video/) is a video

Answer (score 1):

If you are aiming for high efficiency

http://grph.inria.fr/