# Open source java library for minimum cost flow problem

Tags: java, open-source, graph

I am wondering is there any open source Java library for minimum cost flow problem? I have checked jgrapht and it is not helping. Does Any body know such library?

Regards,
Luke

Comment: Can you define what you want better? What exactly do you mean by "minimum cost flow" problem?

Comment: @Falmarri he's probably referring to the Ford-Fulkerson network flow algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm

Comment: I am referring to the Minimum-cost flow problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem

Comment: JUNG2 seems to support two other problems: (i) `Implements the Edmonds-Karp maximum flow algorithm for solving the maximum flow problem.` (ii) a few shortest path algorithms http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.html Maybe you can look into (i) and modify it a bit

Comment: Here are two https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/min_cost_flow_bf https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/min_cost_flow_pot

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a library that is both open source and includes this algorithm, but here are a few places to look if you decide to have a go at implementing it yourself.

The answers to this question: [Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library) identify some of the main Java graph libraries.

This article: [Minimum cost flow problem and its applications](http://forums.ateji.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=36) discusses how to express the problem in [OptimJ](http://www.ateji.com/optimj/index.html). OptimJ is a commercial product with a "free" version.

This book also has half a chapter on the algorithm: [A Java Library of Graph Algorithms and Optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584887184)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [min cost max flow algorithm in Java](http://web.mit.edu/~ecprice/acm/acm08/MinCostMaxFlow.java). There's no license with the code so you may need to contact the page owner for that info.  I've not yet used this code myself.  If it doesn't do the job & you're willing to port some code, I've seen numerous C / C++ implementations.