# any API for handling graph? in java

Tags: java, graph, mindmapping

I would like to use the concept of MindMap
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_map

in a AI program. Is there any API for java? A good api for drawing and manipulating graphs with enough documentation and examples will also do the job.

I dont actually need to represent it graphically , i just need to build the map in any method(used for representing graphs, ) and search in it.

The program shall take a word as input

Search the mindmap for it and display the relevant words.

Comment: I'm confuded: you write "A good api for drawing and manipulating graphs" and then "I dont actually need to represent it graphically". So what do you want exactly? A Java API fro drawing and manipulating graphs ... or what?

Comment: I mean representing a mindmap by adjacency list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list   ..... then i want to do a binary search from the centre to find the topic in the mindmap

Comment: Have you looked at this [question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library) ?

Comment: Thank you.. maybe this shall work.. do you know of any good example of using JGraphT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JGraphT was possible solution for me. I am working on it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)? It's an open-source Java MindMap framework.

Comment: I dont want a program to draw a mind map, i want an API which can be used from within java to handle a mind map

Comment: Ok, clarification. What do you want as input and what do you want as output? Is AI outputing MindMap or using it?