# Java library for graph theory algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-theory

Is there a java library for standard graph theory algorithms like shortest paths etc. The algorithm that I am in particular looking for is finding the largest connected component in a graph.

Answer (score 5):

[JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) graph library should have this. If not then check [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/) as well

Related SO post: [Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)