# Java library to visualize algorithm

Tags: java

Is there any Java library to visualize common data structures (viz.stack queue LL etc) and their access methods?  I just want to simulate what my data structure is doing..

Comment: might help: http://code.google.com/p/jcomplexity/

Comment: @fas..now we'r going on right track...thanks it'll help me

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to visualize the data, check out `JUNG`:

http://jung.sourceforge.net/

If you're talking about visualizing what your code is doing to the data, `JUNG` might still help with that, but just Google searching gave me a lot of results, so try that.

Comment: I know this library but it is useful for graph algorithms but for simple data structures(stack,queue etc) u know any other library?

Comment: Do you want to graph the data? or display what you are doing to the data?

Comment: your best bet may be to go with a network graph - such as github's "Network Graph Viewer" - which would show data being "merged" into and "branched" out of your structure.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your questions:

Do you:

1) want to learn how they work? try google, you will find many good applets which explain the working of algorithms and data structures through simple animation.

2) want to see the behavior in your app, run the app in debug mode.

Comment: No i want a framework which will simulate my data structure eg.if i push element into stack it should visually show me that element is being pushed..a kind of visual debugger...my need is only for some common data structures..not all

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/).

You can find relevant discussion here: [Stackoverflow - Good Java Graph Algorithm Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)