# Graph Algorithma in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)

Is there a complete library in Java that implements several Graph algorithmic problems, e.g. the clique problem

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of the following libraries:

- [the Java Universal Network/Graph Framewor](http://jung.sourceforge.net/),a library that provides a common and extendible language for the modeling, analysis, and visualization of data that can be represented as a graph or network.
- [salvo graph implementation](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5F3CC69D925863EB1E5C2E6C18A4C3284C9D73E4.aspx), focusing on graph data structures.
- last and less least, [JGraphT](http://www.jgrapht.org/), a big library that provides mathematical graph-theory objects and algorithms.

But I'm sure there are thousands more, for specific areas. If you have some particular application in mind, maybe post that in your question, too...