# Java library for storing and processing large (up to 600k vertices) graphs

Tags: java, graph, shortest-path, large-data

I'm working on a project which will involve running algorithms on large graphs.  The largest two have around 300k and 600k vertices (fairly sparse I think).  I'm hoping to find a java library that can handle graphs that large, and also trees of a somewhat smaller size, as one of the algorithms I'll be using involves decomposing a graph into a tree.  Ideally the library would also include breadth first search and Dijkstra's or other shortest-path algorithms.

Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library), I've been looking at a few libraries ([JGraphT](http://jgrapht.sourceforge.net/), [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), [jdsl](http://www.cs.brown.edu/cgc/jdsl/), [yworks](http://docs.yworks.com/yfiles/doc/api/)) but I'm having a hard time finding out how many vertices they can realistically handle.  Looking at their documentation, all I could find was a bit in the [JUNG FAQ](http://jung.sourceforge.net/faq.html#graphsize) that said it could easily handle graphs of upwards of 150k vertices, which is still quite a bit smaller than my graphs...  I'm hoping someone here has used one or more of these libraries and can tell me if it'll handle the graph sizes I need, or if there's some other library that would be better.

For the record I don't need any visualization tools; this is strictly about representing the graphs and trees in data structures and running algorithms on them.

Background if anyone really cares: for a class I'm supposed to implement an algorithm described in a research paper, and run the experiments run in the paper as best I can.  The paper and datasets I'll be using can be found [here](http://dbis.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/index.php?project=TEDI). My professor says I can use any library I can find as long as I can tell what the time/space complexity of the algorithms/data structures are.

Comment: Just found some info on [JGraphT](http://jgrapht-users.107614.n3.nabble.com/Max-limit-of-vertices-td1194057.html). Apparently it should handle these graphs no problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) which is a graphical database which might be a good solution for your problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into this now. It can definitely handle those datasets.

Comment: I'm first going to try one of the in-memory libraries, as that's what's done in the paper so I think my prof would like that better, but if that doesn't work I'll go with Neo4J. It looks easy to use and it has all the algorithms I need.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/) as well. However it is oriented towards visualization.

Also, maybe [Apache Hama](http://incubator.apache.org/hama/) - a distributed computing framework for massive scientific computations e.g., matrix, graph and network algorithms.

[Annas](http://code.google.com/p/annas/) may also interest you - open-source Java framework that was built for developers and researchers in the fields of Graph Theory - AI, Path finding, distributed systems, etc.

Comment: Hmm. The info I've seen makes it seem like this wouldn't be as suitable... In the user manual they start off by going on about swing for example. I don't want to have to mess with the visualization stuff at all. Is that possible, do you know?

Comment: @Maltiriel, you could potentially work on graph model standalone. However, if you don't need to visualize the graph, it is an overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the additional suggestions.  Hama may be a bit much for what I'm doing, but Annas looks very interesting.  I haven't come across either one in my searches before this.

Answer (score 1):

Cassovary https://github.com/twitter/cassovary -project from Twitter can handle very big graphs with Scala (thus JVM) in memory.

Alternatively, GraphChi's Java version can handle even bigger graphs, by using disk: http://code.google.com/p/graphchi-java/

However, GraphChi will not be efficient for exact shortest-path type algorithms, as they require fast random access.

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be a bit late for the you, but for others who have similar questions, I would recommend using **[GraphScope](https://graphscope.io/)**, a one-stop graph computing system developed by Alibaba. It will meet your **needs for large-scale graphs**.

If you want to write your graph algorithm in Java, then you're in luck. GraphScope provides comprehensive Java support. You can use **[GRAPE-JDK](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope/tree/main/analytical_engine/java)**'s user-friendly Java interface to write **your own graph algorithms**.

In addition to the ease of use of the interface, **GRAPE-JDK** also provides high query performance. Using the LLVM4JNI technology provided by **[FastFFI](https://github.com/alibaba/fastFFI)**, it can accelerate JNI calls between Java and C++, thus reducing program execution time. According to [performance report](https://github.com/alibaba/GraphScope/blob/main/analytical_engine/java/performance.md) provided by GraphScope, GRAPE-JDK can even provide execution efficiency that is close to that of C++ programs.

If you would like to learn more about **GRAPE-JDK**, please visit this blog post: [Breaking the Language Barrier in Large Scale Graph Computing](https://graphscope.io/blog/tech/2023/06/19/Breaking-the-Language-Barrier-in-Large-Scale-Graph-Computing).

Disclaimer: I'm an author of GraphScope.