# data structure for Graph in java

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

i am looking to implement a algorithm for the Travel Salesman Problem. I want to model the solution using the **graph** , in this a **vertex** will represent a city and **edge** will represent the cost from one city to another.
At any point i have to compute cost from one city to another like 
        (cityA, cityB)--->cost

What data structure in java should i use for graph?

And what kind of GUI tool or library can i use to represent a graph ?

Comment: Does this have to do with your homework? If so, then tag it as such :)

Comment: How many vertices and edges (max)?

Comment: Maybe take a look at the Sedgewick algorithms book, their examples are in Java

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are free to use external libraries, [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/) is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Why a graph, of course.  Take a look at [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

depending on the size of your problem and your hardware, you might want to take a look at nosql graph databases like: http://neo4j.org/

most of them are easy to handle and some (like neo4j) provide a graph visualization which is nice for debugging purpose.

if you want to develop with as much performance as possible, you might have to create your own simple graph format. Most of the told ones are slow due to a lot of overhead (generics etc.)