# Java code for Graph and its demands

Tags: java, graph

I need to write a graph with some nodes v={1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and edges E={(1-2),(2-3), (3,4),(4-7), (3-6), (2-6), (5-6), (1-5)} and also with some demands D=(s,d)={(1-3),(2-3), (4-5). (7-7), (6-4),(2-7)} which are some path with an exact source an destination for a small network.
How can I write this in Java?  Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting out the nouns you will see that you need a Vertices/Node class, an Edge class and a Demand class.  This will be just the beginning of your solution.  You will also have a Graph or Network class that consists of a list of Nodes, a list of Edges and a list of Demands.  Then you will need to decide where to put the processing methods that use the nodes, edges and demands.

```
> A Node will consist of an integer. 
> An Edge will consist of two Nodes 
> and so on
```

Here is an example

```
public class Node {
   private int nodeNumber;
}
```

Comment: thx , but since i am new to java, can you help me more in details i mean with some java codes for classes

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the weel, you could look into [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/). There are some [examples](https://github.com/jgrapht/jgrapht/wiki) available that give you some ideas of how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

As a start point I can propose you following class structure:

```
class Vertex{
    String id;
    List<Edge> edges;

    public Vertex(String id){
        this.id = id;
        edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    }

    void addEdge(Edge e){
        edges.add(e);
    }
}

class Edge{
   Vertex fromVertex;
   Vertex toVertex;

   Edge(Vertex from, Vertex to){
       this.fromVertex = from;
       this.toVertex = to;
   }
}
```

etc...

If you consider not to implement your own graph and use it from some library take a look at this question:

[Good Java graph algorithm library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574/good-java-graph-algorithm-library)